# How to reduce rendering time of ascx controls in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, database-connection, ascx

I have a reporting system, and its having multiple pages.
So using unified controls combination is one of the feasible way, for that i have opted to use usercontols.

Now, when my project is hosted it took more time to load and fetch data from the database. Rendering details are attached in the image.

The set of user-defined controls has much use for me, since it can be re-used in other pages.

In a single user-defined control, there are 10 to 16 individual controls like drop-downs, radio-button-groups etc.. 
all these are fetching data from the database and have post-back events too.

Can any one tell me that is there any possible way to reduce the rendering time of .ASCX controls. 
[Screen rendering time of on-load event of one page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axPmP.png)

[image: Timeline info of same page]

Comment: The problem can be in so many places... You should look at running a profiler and finding the exact place that is slowing everything down.

Comment: If you use many controls and they do a lot of data operations, they execute synchronously. You may need to redesign your page for asynchronous loading. May be, you want to show page and then use AJAX to load some parts of it. I wouldn't recommend to load async during page lifecycle.

Comment: @T.S , Thank you for the valid response. Is it possible to fill drop-downs of the ASCX control in Ajax , and later plug into ASPX page.

Comment: @the_lotus,  I have attached the profiler details of one of the pages, Its from the document itself.

Comment: You need to profile the code. You need to know exactly where it's slow, which function. Maybe the drawing is slow, maybe the database is slow, maybe you have an algorithm that was badly written, ect...

Comment: These days everything possible http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-ASPNet-DropDownList-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx